# spring boot, jackson and localdate

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, localdate

I use spring boot with mysql

in my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

In my build.gradle I have

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
```

In my java class

import java.time.LocalDate;

```
@Entity
public class WebSite implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long webSiteId;

    private LocalDate date;
    ...
}
```

When this table is created,

date field is created like a TINYBLOB

Why is not a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with Jackson, but rather that whatever you are using for ORM doesn't know how to convert a Java LocalDate to a MySQL Date.

There are two ways to do this. If you are using Hibernate, you simply include `org.hibernate:hibernate-java8` in your dependencies.

Alternatively, if you want just use JPA, you need to create an Attribute Converter. For example:

```java
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

The Attribute Converter will handle converting between a Java LocalDate and MySQL Date.

See: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/